# Problem inserting data from my Qt App to mySQL DataBase with C++

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I'm trying to insert some datas from the QLineEdits to mySql database, i used the binding method mentionned in the Qt documentation, but it doesn't insert anything in the database:

```
 query.prepare("INSERT INTO Candidat (ID, Nom, Prenom, Email, Disponibilité, Canal, Profil, Nba_experience, Chemin_cv, ID_recruteur , Adresse)"
                     "VALUES (:ID, :Nom, :Prenom, :Email, :Disponibilité, :Canal, :Profil, :Nba_experience, :Chemin_cv, :ID_recruteur , :Adresse)");

       int NB = RNBAExp->text().toInt();

       query.bindValue(":ID",RID->text());
       query.bindValue(":Nom,",RNom->text());
       query.bindValue(":Prenom",RPrenom->text());
       query.bindValue(":Email",REmail->text());
       query.bindValue(":Disponibilité",RDisponibilite->currentText());
       query.bindValue(":Canal",RCanal->currentText());
       query.bindValue(":Profil",RProfil->text());
       query.bindValue(":Nba_experience",NB);
       query.bindValue(":Chemin_cv",RCheminCV->text());
       query.bindValue(":ID_recruteur",RIDRecruteur->text());
       query.bindValue(":Adresse",RAdresse->text());

       if (query.exec())
       {
           QMessageBox::information(this,"Ajout BD","Le candidat est ajouté dans la bse de données");
       }
```

BUT when i compile my QT App with this query,it runs successfully. With the first code, it doesn't and i don't know why :

```
query.prepare("INSERT INTO Candidat (ID, Nom, Prenom, Email, Disponibilité, Canal, Profil, Nba_experience, Chemin_cv, ID_recruteur , Adresse)"
              "VALUES ('df', 'fffd', 'fsf', 'fsfff', 'fffff', 'ffffff', 'ffffff', 4, 'ffffff', 'BO1', 'fffffff')");


       if (query.exec())
       {
           QMessageBox::information(this,"Ajout BD","Le candidat est ajouté dans la bse de données");
       }
```

Comment: You're missing the colon here: `query.bindValue("Disponibilité",RDisponibilite->currentText());`. It should be: `query.bindValue(":Disponibilité",RDisponibilite->currentText());`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i changed it but still doesn't work!

Comment: Why don't you add an `else` block to `if (query.exec())` and add this: `qWarning() << "ERROR: " << query.lastError().text();`. That will give you a better idea why your query is failing. Also, can you add a space before `VALUES`.

Comment: Thanks, i did it and this is the error : QSqlError("1054", "QMYSQL: Unable to execute query", "Unknown column 'NULLé' in 'field list'") , So i changed the name of the column "Disponibilité" to "Disponibilite" and it works now.

Comment: Ok. Good. The query was failing because it didn't recognise the 'é' character.